# Nginx including conf from conf.d but still loading default settings

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

All configurations are being included and conf test is passed too. But Nginx is still serving the default HTML from `/usr/share/nginx/html`, instead of location root from conf file in conf.d directory.

**conf file** from conf.d directory

```
upstream django {
    server          unix:///tmp/server.sock;
}

server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     server.test.com;
    access_log      /srv/source/logs/access-nginx.log;
    error_log       /srv/source/logs/error-nginx.log;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass      django;
        include         /srv/source/conf/uwsgi/params;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root            /srv/source/;
        index           index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root            /srv/source/media/;
        index           index.html index.htm;
    }

    # alias favicon.* to static
    location ~ ^/favicon.(\w*)$ {
        alias /srv/source/static/favicon.$1;
    }

}
```

Comment: are you 100% sure that you are calling your server as http://server.test.com ? because this may be an issue - you are being redirected to the default server which is defined elsewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `nginx` config is in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.  By default that file includes the following lines (at least that is the case on rhel based and arch based distros):

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Thanks to the `root` in the `server` section `nginx` will keep serving the files under that directory until you comment our these lines.  This happens just after `conf.d` is loaded (as noted in the snippet above).

No matter what you change inside `conf.d` that last part of the file will still be loaded.  Since it is that file (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) that loads the configs in `conf.d`.

And yes, you definitely should comment out that default `server` if you plan to use `nginx`.

Comment: This is not correct. It is perfectly fine to have multiple server blocks in nginx config and configuration from one would not interfere with configuration from another.

Comment: @solarissmoke not sure about correct or not but grochmal's solution worked, as soon as i commented out the default server my app started working.

Comment: @rayman that is because your other server becomes the default server if another isn't specified. The comment from @Jerzyk points to what the actual issue was - most likely that your `server_name` doesn't match the host your are serving on.

Comment: I place that name just for elaboration server name perfectly matches host name.

Comment: I was much more worried about the default `server_name  _;`.  If he kills the `default_server` he can properly debug his own.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and once I commented the default root         /usr/share/nginx/html, it automatically redirect to my intended server which I have specified in conf.d folder @solarissmoke. I understand the other becomes the default if none is specified, but my server_name already match the host. Could I have a subdomain redirecting to different server with its domain? I have 2 VPS and the domain is redirecting to a different VPS than it's subdomain. Is it possible? Thankyou!

Comment: @Anthonius at that point it is time to stop using the default config files. What i do is that, having place all my `nginx` configs in `/usr/local/src/webd` is go `ln -s /usr/local/src/ops/nginx/webd /etc/nginx/webd` and `echo 'include webd/nginx.conf;' > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` .  This effectively makes all nginx config mine, without defautl quirks.  Then in my configs i got `server { listen 80 default_server backlog=2048; server_name _; return 301 $scheme://grochmal.org; }`.  I do this in a dockerfile for simplicity of deployment but it does not need to be in docker.